# How to get twitter user id matching a search query

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm new to Ruby and I'm using [`sferik gem`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to get user id matching a search query (first result). The ultimate goal is to get users id matching with a column from a json file

I've read the documentation but don't know really how start... any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `sferik` gem is just a wrapper around Twitter's REST API, so any responses you get will conform to their contract. If you search for tweets, you'll get [Tweet Objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object).

Taking an example from `sferik`, doing a search a getting the user_id for the first result:

```
# for the User ID (get it as string if you want to use it later in JSON)
client.search("to:justinbieber marry me", result_type: "recent").first.user.id_str

# for the User Screen name
client.search("to:justinbieber marry me", result_type: "recent").first.user.screen_name
```